# Limit with Stolz-Cesàro theorem: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt3+\ldots+n\sqrt n}{n^2 \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt3+\ldots+n\sqrt n}{n^2 \sqrt{n}}= \text{?}$$

Book has no answers.
It's on Stolz-Cesàro theorem lesson, if that helps. Can't find a solution.

Comment: @AlexR: I do not think that is a proper edit.  You should have left it in the explicit summation as the OP had written it.  The editing should reflect not only the correct expression, but also the limits on the OP's knowledge.

Comment: @RonGordon You should have still left the title (100% MathJax is discouraged for various reasons) and also used $\sqrt \cdot$ where possible to improve readability.

Comment: @AlexR: OK, agreed. We're even now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the direct application of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+2\sqrt{2}+...+n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 \sqrt{n}}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1+2\sqrt{2}+...+(n+1)\sqrt{n+1})-(1+2\sqrt{2}+...+n\sqrt{n})}{(n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}-n^2\sqrt{n}}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}-n^2\sqrt{n}}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}((n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}+n^2\sqrt{n})}{((n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}-n^2\sqrt{n})((n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}+n^2\sqrt{n})}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}((n+1)^2 \sqrt{n+1}+n^2\sqrt{n})}{(n+1)^5-n^5}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^4+(n+1)n^2\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1+n^{-1})^4+(1+n^{-1})\sqrt{1+n^{-1}}}{5+10n^{-1}+10n^{-2}+5n^{-3}+n^{-4}}\\
=&\frac{2}{5}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Lord_Farin, fixed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've taken the liberty to change it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven't thought of amplifying at the 4th line. Got it now!

Comment: @Mathstudent Now you can accept one of the answers by clicking green checkmark under votes counter

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, this is a Riemann sum:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left ( \frac{k}{n}\right )^{3/2} = \int_0^1 dx \, x^{3/2} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: thanks for answering, but I'm in 11th grade, don't know how to use integrals yet

Comment: @Mathstudent: surprised you are supposed to know Stolz-Cesaro, yet no integrals.  Oh well.  Anyway, at least you  know what to work towards.

Comment: @AlexR How do you use the geometric series here?

Comment: @gt6989b nevermind, I oversaw something